# Flip parts of a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

This is a fairly straightforward question.

I am wondering if there's a way to flip part of a string with part from another one in one line, or without a "temporary" variable. Here's what I mean:

```
s1 = "asdfghjkl;"
s2 = "qwertyuiop"


to_flip = s1[3..-1]
s1[3..-1] = s2[3..-1]
s2[3..-1] = to_flip


s1 # => "asdrtyuiop"
s2 # => "qwefghjkl;"
```

Ruby seems to always have some sort of one-line trick for everything, and I'm hoping one of you knows what it is for this :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, `String` slices can be assigned to.

```
s1[3..-1], s2[3..-1] = s2[3..-1], s1[3..-1]
```

Here, commas are used to assign to multiple things at once, which Ruby also allows. This is because the statement

```
a, b = b, a
```

Swaps the values of `a` and `b` (or, more specifically, assigns one to the other.)